# Express-validator doesn't want find any duplicates in database

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using `Express-Validator` to validation my fields in forms on front, but `exists()` function doesn't work.

I have another form (register form) where I'm using EV (Express-Validator) and in this case everything is okay, I'm doing the same with second form and here it validation doesn't work.

game.js (routing)

```js
const app = require('express')();
const gameController = require('../controllers/gameController');
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');

module.exports = () => {
  app.post('/add', [
    check('title').exists().withMessage('The PBF Game with this title is actually in database'),
    check('link').exists().withMessage('The PBF Game with this website link is actually in database')
  ], gameController.addGame);

  return app;
}
```

gameController.js

```js
const db = require('../models');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

const validation = {
  size: 40960,
  type: 'image/png'
}

const path = 'uploads/';

module.exports = {
  addGame(req, res, next) {
    const { title, link, description } = req.body;
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ status: res.statusCode, message: errors.array() });
    } else if (req.files.icon.size > validation.size) {
      return res.status(400).json({ status: res.statusCode, message: [{ 'msg': 'Your file has more than 50KB!' }] });
    } else if (req.files.icon.mimetype !== validation.type) {
      return res.status(400).json({ status: res.statusCode, message: [{ 'msg': 'You can upload only PNG files!' }] });
    } else {
      let file = req.files.icon;

      file.mv(path + new Date().getTime() + '-' + file.name, err => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({ message: [{ 'msg': err }] });
        }

        db.game.create({ title: title, link: link, icon: path + file.name, description: description, flag: false });
        return res.status(200).json({ status: res.statusCode, message: 'The game has been added for verification. It should briefly appear in the selection field in the profile. If not, it means that the administrator has not approved the request.' });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Express-Validator not check if value exist in database and pass empty array to controller where I'm checking file and trying return correct response. User gets success response (if file is correct) but my server console display red alert about 'validation error' and no value is putting into database, but what I said before, user gets success response. Where is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't check if it exists in your db. For example `check('title').exists()` will only check if `req.body.title` exists. It has nothing to do with your database.

Comment: Yes, now I know it. Just was suprised, because with login or email in my second form controller, it works how I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express validator can only validate the requests. It CAN NOT validate if a value is already present in database. For that, you need to query your database and check.

For example, the validation `check('title').exists()` will check if `title` field is present in the request, NOT in the database.

Comment: Are you sure? Because in this case -> https://jsfiddle.net/sykq56z7/
validation works very well even `exists` is check.

Comment: Yes, password/email format, present/omission of a field in a request can be handled by express validator, but checks on data already existing, NO.

Comment: Oh, so... I have to write my own middleware which will be check if value existing in database. Thank you.

Comment: @Jakub you can use custom validators for that. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html